# How can I download and Use Angular project off of Stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, angular, stackblitz

So I have a project available on stackblitz that I want to use offline for my own purposes. for reference, here is the link to what I want to use- https://stackblitz.com/edit/nvs-angular-search-dropdown-istnzp. So, I tried to download the code and planned to run it using `npm install` and `ng serve`. but I am getting lots of errors on running `npm install` saying like this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angular@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^12.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"7.0.4" from @angular/compiler-cli@7.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~7.0.0" from the root project     
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\cnaag\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cnaag\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-06T10_39_43_617Z-debug.log
```

Any help in this regard would be amazing!

Comment: And did you try what the message suggests, ie. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: yes, It wasn't helpful. It still refused to move ahead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of NPM, install Yarn on your machine and run yarn install